# Send an email from a Python3 script with localhost?

Tags: python-3.x, mail-server, smtplib

I need to send mails from my Python3 script. Now it does, but my gmail password is visible and I cannot trust in any admin of this machine, so the solution I see is to mount a local mail server. To do some tests, I was trying to execute a script (this one: [SMTP sink server](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/96/)). While this one is running, I execute my old script with some changes:

```
import smtplib

# server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost:25')
# smtp.ehlo()
# server.starttls()
# smtp.ehlo()
# server.login('my_account@gmail.com', 'my_password')
server.login(None, None)
server.sendmail('Me <my_account@gmail.com'>, ['to_user@gmail.com'], 'Hi!'.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I understand the script at the link will create a file in the folder where it is with the mail content, but nothing happens, because I get this error message:

```
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

I googled and I think this could be sorted out if I uncomment the line `server.starttls()`, but it gives another error, which is supposed to be solved with the lines `smtp.ehlo()`, but not in my case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to send the email, what I only had to do was removing this line:

```
server.login(None, None)
```